# Up-to-date jQuery books

Tags: jquery

jQuery just released version 1.6.4. Despite that, the list of "books about jQuery" at the bottom of jquery.com all deal with jQuery 1.4 or below. Where can I find jQuery literature  dealing with the more cutting edge features of jQuery available in 2011?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page ?

Comment: If there is one thing I find bad of jQuery, it's definitely their online documentation.

Comment: @Randomblue: What don't you like about it? I've found it covers things very well.

Comment: @Randomblue: Would you care to explain what is bad about their documentation? Have you read the MySQL Manual? That personally is what I define as bad. jQuery's is almost at par with PHP's documentation

Comment: Everything seems so muddled up. The core documentation, the UI documentation, demos pages, pluggin pages. It needs a lot of getting used to!

Comment: The documentation was written as a reference and not exactly as a manual. Have you tried reading the tutorials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need one. The jQuery documentation is very rich and is sufficient.

If you really want to know how things are done. Read other people's code, especially easy since you can see `js` files unlike server side scripts like `PHP`. Go to a cool site, install Firebug and simply try to learn just "how they did it". It will not be easy at first (it never is) but you will pick up a lot of things as you go along.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way that you can expect book publishing to run at web speed.  Your only hope if you must be current is the Internet.

It might be your understanding of jQuery that's muddled.  If you've never seen jQuery before, I'd bet that those 1.4 books would be a good place to start.  The basic ideas are unchanged.